# Saving output from parallel jobs in R into one file

Tags: r, shell, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am running a rather lengthy job that I need to replicate 100 times, thus I have turned to the foreach capability in R which I then run on a 8-core cluster through a shell script. I am trying to input all of my results from each run to the same file. I have included a simplified version of my code.

```
cl<-makeCluster(core-1)
registerDoParallel(cl,cores=core)
SigEpsilonSq<-list()
SigLSq<-list()
RatioMat<-list()
foreach(p=1:100) %dopar%{

functions defining my variables{...}

  for(i in 1:fMaxInd){
   rhoSqjMatr[,i]<-1/(1+Bb[i])*(CbAdj+AbAdj*XjBarAdj+BbAdj[i]*XjSqBarAdj)/(dataZ*dataZ)
     sigmaEpsSqV[i]<-mean(rhoSqjMatr[,i])
     rhoSqjMatr[,i]<-rhoSqjMatr[,i]/sigmaEpsSqV[i]
     biasCorrV[,i]<-sigmaEpsSqV[i]/L*gammaQl(rhoSqjMatr[,i])
     Qcbar[,i]<-Qflbar-biasCorrV[,i]
     sigmaExtSq[,i]<-sigmaSqExt(sigmaEpsSqV[i], rhoSqjMatr[,i])
     ratioMatr[,i]<-sigmaExtSq[,i]/(sigmaL*sigmaL)#ratio (sigma_l^e)^2/(sigmaL)^2

   }   

   sigmaEpsSqV<-as.matrix(sigmaEpsSqV)
   SigEpsilonSq[[p]]<-sigmaEpsSqV
   SigLSq[[p]]<-sigmaExtSq
   RatioMat[[p]]<-ratioMatr 

} #End of the dopar loop

stopCluster(cl)

write.csv(SigEpsilonSq,file="Sigma_Epsilon_Sq.csv")
write.csv(SigLSq,file="Sigma_L_Sq.csv")
write.csv(RatioMat,file="Ratio_Matrix.csv")
```

When the job completes, my .csv files are empty. I believe I'm not quite understanding how the foreach saves results and how I can access them. I would like to avoid having to merge files manually. Also, do I need to write
    stopCluster(cl)
at the end of my foreach loop or do I wait until the very end? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you hover over a tag, you can see how it should be used. **parallel.foreach** is a **.NET** thing.

Comment: @Laurel You could have changed it to the correct [tag:parallel-foreach] yourself.

Comment: @svick I just wanted to help the author learn how to use tags. (I also didn't know about the correct tag. I don't know R, so I wasn't sure if it was something important enough to warrant a tag existing.) I appreciate you adding the tag anyway.

Comment: Thank you both. I usually don't post, so I'm new to how everything works. I will be sure to tag properly in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how foreach works. You should look into examples. You need to use .combine, if you want to output something from your parallelized jobs.
Also, instead of this:

```
sigmaEpsSqV<-as.matrix(sigmaEpsSqV)
SigEpsilonSq[[p]]<-sigmaEpsSqV
SigLSq[[p]]<-sigmaExtSq
RatioMat[[p]]<-ratioMatr
```

You have to re-write something like this:

```
list(as.matrix(sigmaEpsSqV),sigmaEpsSqV,sigmaExtSq,ratioMatr)
```

You can also use rbind, cbind, c,... to aggregate the results into one final output.
You can even your own combine function, example:

```
.combine=function(x,y)rbindlist(list(x,y))
```

---

The solution below should work. The output should be a list of lists. However it might be painful to retreive results and save them in the correct format. If so, you should design your own .combine function.

```
cl<-makeCluster(core-1)
registerDoParallel(cl,cores=core)
SigEpsilonSq<-list()
SigLSq<-list()
RatioMat<-list()
results = foreach(p=1:100, .combine=list) %dopar%{

  functions defining my variables{...}

  for(i in 1:fMaxInd){
   rhoSqjMatr[,i]<-1/(1+Bb[i])*(CbAdj+AbAdj*XjBarAdj+BbAdj[i]*XjSqBarAdj)/(dataZ*dataZ)
     sigmaEpsSqV[i]<-mean(rhoSqjMatr[,i])
     rhoSqjMatr[,i]<-rhoSqjMatr[,i]/sigmaEpsSqV[i]
     biasCorrV[,i]<-sigmaEpsSqV[i]/L*gammaQl(rhoSqjMatr[,i])
     Qcbar[,i]<-Qflbar-biasCorrV[,i]
     sigmaExtSq[,i]<-sigmaSqExt(sigmaEpsSqV[i], rhoSqjMatr[,i])
     ratioMatr[,i]<-sigmaExtSq[,i]/(sigmaL*sigmaL)#ratio (sigma_l^e)^2/(sigmaL)^2

   }   

   list(as.matrix(sigmaEpsSqV),sigmaEpsSqV,sigmaExtSq,ratioMatr)

} #End of the dopar loop

stopCluster(cl)

#Then you extract and save results
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This definitely helped a lot.