# %dopar% safe way of write to csv inside foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

[EDITED]

It is a general question: I have seen some posts saying that it is not a good idea to use foreach and write.csv inside a foreach loop due to different cores trying to write in the file at the same time, resulting in missing results. Still, I need to write in an external file inside the parallel loop to get my output (500000+ rows and 10+ columns). Otherwise, it crushes for memory issues.  So, I would like to know if there is a more safe way to write a result file within a foreach loop.
I appreciate any help on this

I am adding some more info and a much more simple code and data than what I actually have.

Description: I have two different polygons layers (sf, polygon), each with 500000+ sf. I need to calculate the area of different raster classes (1 raster layer with 3 classes) within each one of the polygons. This is the most time-consuming part of the script, specifically because I need to use sf::sf_intersection multiple times. Then, I use many different combinations of if-else and rules to populate a df with values and rules.

This is the original code, which I get memory issues with the original data:

```
require(sf)
require(raster)
require(rgdal)
require(rgeos)
require(dplyr)
require(stars)


## Sample data
set.seed(131)

sample_raster = raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5, xmn = 0, xmx = 11, ymn = 0, ymx = 11)
values(sample_raster) = rep(1:3, length.out = ncell(sample_raster))
crs(sample_raster) = CRS('+init=EPSG:4326')
plot(sample_raster, axes=T)
sample_raster

##

m = rbind(c(0,0), c(1,0), c(1,1), c(0,1), c(0,0))
p = st_polygon(list(m))
n = 100
l = vector("list", n)
for (i in 1:n)
  l[[i]] = p + 10 * runif(2)
sample_poly = st_sfc(l)


data = data.frame(PR_ID = seq(1:100),
       COND1 = rep(1:10, length.out = 100))
sample_poly = st_sf(cbind(data, sample_poly))


plot(sample_poly, col = sf.colors(categorical = TRUE, alpha = .5), add=T)
sample_poly = sample_poly %>% st_set_crs(4326)
sample_poly

## 





## Code
require(parallel)
require(foreach)  
require(doParallel) 

idall = as.character(sample_poly$PR_ID)
area = as.numeric(st_area(sample_poly))/10000


# i=1
# listID = idall
# mainpoly = sample_poly
# mainras = sample_raster
# mainpolyarea = area


  
per.imovel.paralallel = function (listID, mainpoly, mainras, mainpolyarea) { # Starting the function
  
  ## Setting the parallel work up into your computer
  UseCores = detectCores()-1 
  cl  = parallel::makeCluster(UseCores, output="") 
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
  

  writeLines(c(""), "log.txt") # Creates a LOG FILE in the folder to follow processing 
  
  
  FOREACH.RESULT = foreach(i = 1:length(listID), .packages=c('raster', 'rgdal', 'rgeos', 'dplyr', 'parallel', 
                                                       'doParallel', 'sf', 'stars'), .inorder = T , .combine ='rbind') %dopar% 
  { # Stating the paral-loop
      
      
      sink("log.txt", append=TRUE)  # LOG FILE in the home folder
      cat(paste(i, "of", length(listID), as.character(Sys.time()),"\n")) # Write to LOG FILE
      sink() # end diversion of output
      
      
      ########################
      ### Pick one poly
      px = sf::st_buffer(mainpoly[mainpoly$PR_ID == listID[i],], # Conditional to select the geometry PR_ID in position i
                              dist = 0.1)                             # buffer = 0 w/ byid, selects the geometry 
      
      
      ########################
      ### Intersect with raster and get area
      px2 = sf::st_buffer(px, dist = 0.1) # Buffer because raster::mask() masks out partially covered cells since it call rasterize() first
      desm_prop = raster::crop(mainras, as_Spatial(px2))
      
      
      
      desm_prop_shp = if(all(is.na(values(desm_prop)))){NULL
      } else {sf::st_intersection(st_cast(sf::st_as_sf(stars::st_as_stars(desm_prop)), "POLYGON"), px)} 
      
      names(desm_prop_shp)[1] = if(any(names(desm_prop_shp) == "layer")){"values"
      } else {NULL}
      
      
      
      desm_prop_bet0108 = if(is.null(desm_prop_shp)){NULL
      } else {desm_prop_shp[desm_prop_shp$values == 1, ]} 
      
      desm_prop_bet0108 = if(is.null(desm_prop_bet0108) | length(desm_prop_bet0108) == 0){NULL
      } else if(length(desm_prop_bet0108$values) == 0){NULL
      } else {desm_prop_bet0108}
      
      
      desm_prop_after08 = if(is.null(desm_prop_shp)){NULL
      } else {desm_prop_shp[desm_prop_shp$values == 2, ]}
      
      desm_prop_after08 = if(is.null(desm_prop_after08) | length(desm_prop_after08) == 0){NULL
      } else if(length(desm_prop_after08$values) == 0){NULL
      } else {desm_prop_after08}
      
      
      desm_prop_upto00 = if(is.null(desm_prop_shp)){NULL
      } else {desm_prop_shp[desm_prop_shp$values == 3, ]}
      
      desm_prop_upto00 = if(is.null(desm_prop_upto00) | length(desm_prop_upto00) == 0){NULL
      } else if(length(desm_prop_upto00$values) == 0){NULL
      } else {desm_prop_upto00}
      
      
      
      area_desm_prop_bet0108 <- if(is.null(desm_prop_bet0108)){0 
      } else { sum(as.numeric(sf::st_area(desm_prop_bet0108)/10000))} # Deforestation area in PX 2001 - 2008
      
      area_desm_prop_after08 <- if(is.null(desm_prop_after08)){0  
      } else { sum(as.numeric(sf::st_area(desm_prop_after08)/10000))} # Deforestation area in PX after 2008
      
      area_desm_prop_upto00 <- if(is.null(desm_prop_upto00)){0 
      } else { sum(as.numeric(sf::st_area(desm_prop_upto00)/10000))} # Deforestation area in PX upto 2000
      
      ########################
      # RESULTS
      TEMP.RESULTS = data.frame(PR_ID = as.character(listID[i]),
                                PR_AREA_HA = mainpolyarea[i],
                                
                                PR_D09 = area_desm_prop_after08,
                                PR_D0108 = area_desm_prop_bet0108,
                                PR_D00 = area_desm_prop_upto00)
      
      
      return (TEMP.RESULTS)
      
    } # Ending the loop
  

return (FOREACH.RESULT) 
parallel::stopCluster(cl) # stop cluster
stopImplicitCluster() # stop cluster
gc()
  
} # Ending the function


#####################################################################################################

results_feach = per.imovel.paralallel (listID = idall, mainpoly = sample_poly, mainras = sample_raster, mainpolyarea = area)
warnings()
```

I have also tried @mischva11 (modified) suggestion by adding this:

```
length_of_chunk = round(length(idall)/(length(idall)/10)) # generate chunks of 10 lines
lchunks = split(idall, sort(rep_len(1:length_of_chunk, length(idall))))

for (z in 1:length_of_chunk){
  
  # split up the data in chunks
  idall_chunk = as.vector(unlist(lchunks[z]))
  results_chunk = per.imovel.paralallel (listID = idall_chunk, mainpoly = sample_poly, mainras = sample_raster, mainpolyarea = area)
  
  # save your foreach results for each chunk, append after the first one
  if (z == 1) {write.table(results_chunk, file = "TESTDATAresults1.csv")
    }else {write.table(results_chunk, file = "TESTDATAresults1.csv", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE)}
  
  print(NULL) # print(results_chunk)
}
```

It works like a charm for this example.

BUT, I have a setback when running it with the real script/data:   it takes ages for the foreach to close. I am watching my machine performance and log file.. after processing all lines of my sf object, my CPU work goes down as expected, but it still takes more than 30min (i did not wait for it to completely finish) to close the foreach function.
Because of it, I thought about writing the output on the flow inside the foreach work. But clearly it is not a good idea as explained here. I have seen some posts about the package 'flock' which look the output file for writing the output. I have not tested but it sounds promising.

Comment: is it necessary to handle the 500000+ rows at the same time? I guess not, otherwise you would have a memory error beforehand. One approach would be to use just chunks of your file. Could you please give some insight what your code does.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36827221/8245406) can help.

Comment: It is not necessary to handle all at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that you need communication between the cores. One core has to wait for the next one until it's finished writing in the csv. That's not easily done and not possible with `foreach` as far as I now. `foreach` does provide this method with the variable `inorder`(by default true). You are telling us, you got memory issues. So one solution is to chunk up your output if it's possible. I do not have a good dataset for this example, so I use mtcars which will be filled by `NA`s

```
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)


registerDoParallel(4)

# split your output here, I use 5 chunks here. My data is mtcars */
length_of_chunk <-round(nrow(mtcars)/5)
for ( z in 1:length_of_chunk-1){
  x<-0
  #here the data gets split up
  data <- mtcars[(z*length_of_chunk):(z*length_of_chunk+length_of_chunk),]
  #foreach with those 5 datarows
  results <- foreach(i=1:length_of_chunk, .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
    #***your code***
    y = data[i,]
    return(y)
  }
  print(results)
  # save your foreach results and then begin again
  if (z==1) {write.table(results, file= "test.csv")}
  else {write.table(results, file="test.csv", append=TRUE, col.names = FALSE)}
}
```